# Big Query - data de-Identification PII

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am looking for a simple way to de-identificate data in BigQuery (and in SQL in general), that handle:

- Anonymize Personally identifiable information (PII) with a unique random value
- Always have the same de-identificate value for a PII value
- Have the possibility to retrieve the original value

I have tried to implement a solution, but I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to handle this. In our database, we don't have a lot of data to anonymise (max 100 000 entries).

**This is a simple exemple of the solution:**

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA dataset_raw_data; -- (only Admin has access to this dataset)
CREATE SCHEMA dataset_clean_data; -- (all team have access to this dataset)
CREATE table dataset_raw_data.users(
    id string,
    email_pii string,
    name_pii string
)
CREATE table dataset_clean_data.users(
    id string,
    email string,
    name string
)
```

I created a mapping table (only accessible by the Admin):

```sql
create table dataset_raw_data.pii_mapping(
    pii_value STRING,
    anonimize_value STRING
)
```

And this is my script to populate the table `dataset_clean_data.users`. If this is the right approach, the objective will be to create a procedure that generates these requests dynamically

```sql
-- Insert missing values in table dataset_raw_data.pii_mapping
insert into dataset_raw_data.pii_mapping
select lower(users.pii_value) as pii_value, GENERATE_UUID() as anonimize_value
from (
    select distinct email_pii as pii_value from dataset_raw_data.users
    union distinct
    select distinct name_pii as pii_value from dataset_raw_data.users
) as base_table
LEFT JOIN dataset_raw_data.pii_mapping as pii_mapping
  ON lower(base_table.pii_value) = pii_mapping.pii_value 
WHERE pii_mapping.pii_value  IS NULL
and base_table.pii_value IS NOT NULL;

-- Populate the table dataset_clean_data.users
insert into table dataset_clean_data.users
select base_table.id as id
pii_mapping1.anonimize_value as email
pii_mapping2.anonimize_value as name
from 
    dataset_raw_data.users as base_table,
    dataset_raw_data.pii_mapping as pii_mapping1,
    dataset_raw_data.pii_mapping as pii_mapping2
where 
    lower(base_table.email) = pii_mapping1.pii_value 
    AND lower(base_table.name) = pii_mapping2.pii_value 
;
```

So at the end I have those data:

```
select * from dataset_raw_data.users LIMIT 1;   -- 1 | bob@gmail.com | Bob
select * from dataset_clean_data.users LIMIT 1; -- 1 | 7d25df8d-4b4d-46ad-9df3-8c71bf092f9f | 1f042eaa-a6b1-4b86-95a9-f6188d3f70d7
```

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Google-bigquery assist you encrypting sensitive information. You have these topics to look for:

- [Customer managed encryption](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/customer-managed-encryption)
- [Custom keys encrypt](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-key-encrypt)

For more information you can check the bigquery documentation about it by clicking [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/encryption-at-rest).

So, for your question, I would recommended use what google already implement, avoiding redundancy in the process. Still, focusing solely in your scenario, which looks like, [a substitution cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher), if it fits your specific scenario, it works, to make it into a functional procedure there are scripting commands that will help you achieve it. Check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) for information about scripting.

Note aside, if we go with sql databases in general, I think one of the most popular approach is to have the data encrypted as soon as it gets into the table when table is inserted/selected - encrypted/decrypted respectively. Most supported usage is at column level, support for other kind of encryption scopes varies from database to database. Check this links to find more information for a practical sample of column level encryption:

- [Encryption at column level](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-the-column-level-sql-server-encryption/)

**Update 16/11/2021**: Added additional link regarding encryption concepts in bigquery

- [Authenticated encryption with associated data - AEAD concepts](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aead-encryption-concepts)

**Bigquery sample**:

```
/* Create raw data table */
create or replace table `project-id.data-set.bikeshare_trips` as (
SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips` 
where  start_time < '2014-01-01' limit 100
)

/* Create key table from data table */
create table `project-id.data-set.biketrips_keys` (
    trip_id INT64,
    keyset BYTES
) AS
Select trip_id,KEYS.NEW_KEYSET('AEAD_AES_GCM_256') as keyset from `project-id.data-set.bikeshare_trips`

/* Create encrypted table from uncrypted raw data table */
create table `project-id.data-set.biketrips_encrypted`
(
    trip_id INT64,
    subscriber_type BYTES 
) as 
select trip_id,
       AEAD.ENCRYPT(
           (select keyset from `project-id.data-set.biketrips_keys` keys where keys.trip_id=trips.trip_id),subscriber_type,CAST(trips.trip_id AS STRING)
       ) 
from `project-id.data-set.bikeshare_trips` trips

/* decrypt from encrypted data table */
select trip_id,
       AEAD.DECRYPT_STRING(
           (select keyset from `project-id.data-set.biketrips_keys` keys where keys.trip_id=trips.trip_id),subscriber_type,CAST(trips.trip_id AS STRING)
       ) 
from `project-id.data-set.biketrips_encrypted` trips
```

Note: [original source](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-encryption-functions-part-i-data-deletion-retention-with-crypto-shredding-7085ecf6e53f)

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for the answer. I'm currently testing but it seems to meet all 3 criteria. If it works, I will add examples and accept the answer. However, it uses another Google service: it increases the dependency on Google Cloud Platform. In addition, I find that the solution is **not easy to implement**. The documentation seems to be incomplete, it feels like a "beta" documentation. There are some points that need further clarification. For exemple, the behaviour of key rotation period. So other answers are welcome.

Comment: You can find additional info about keysets and bigquery encryption concepts on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aead-encryption-concepts). I also updated the answer to have that information on it.

Comment: About samples, have you try porting this [sample](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-encryption-functions-part-i-data-deletion-retention-with-crypto-shredding-7085ecf6e53f) l think it fits what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the example, I understand better. What is the point of using encryption in place of “simple mapping”? The person who has access to all tables in BigQuery can still read the PII data. Is it to complicate the life of a potential attacker? We want to be able to re-identify personal data so it’s normal, but the solution with encryption function looks more complicate so I would like to be sure to understand the advantages.

Comment: It follows the pattern of modern vaults, when only a handful of person have access to all passwords (usually the security It team) and not the entire organization. Also encryption comes at a cost so you should know when actually apply. Back into your re-identify case, well you can mask it using a function or view which actually implements the unpleasant code so hard stuff its only do it once.